# Public web chat room on HipChat

Tags: hipchat

I see that at http://blog.gleam.io/hipchat/ is talked about "Public Chat Rooms" which I see you can open and participate through a web page, without signing in HipChat, by just choosing your nickname (Full name as they say on the page. Actual chat room is at https://www.hipchat.com/gXGrGMHTO .

How can you create a public chat room on HipChat that is publicly accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stuart McKeown helped me out. You have to:

1. Create public chat room.
2. Open Windows client
3. Open/Enter the public chat room you have created
4. Click on bottom right checkbox "Guest access is off". [image] Clicking on it should change it to "on".

Note that you have to be Admin to be able to allow guest access.